# Finding AndroidAccessory documentation for read()

Tags: android, arduino

I need some help finding the documentation of .read(). I know this is easy, but I can't find it. I've search and searched, and this page on the android side is the closest I could find - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html.

Here is the arduino code splice I am trying to interpret. I need to know how to modify the read() part for my needs. Thanks

```
AndroidAccessory acc("Manufacturer",
"Model",
"Description",
"1.0",
"hey.now.what",
"0000000012345678");

acc.read(msgIn, sizeof(msgIn), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking the same thing as you did. After googling around and trying it by myself, I managed to build up something like this:

Declaration:

```cpp
int AndroidAccessory::read(void *buff, int len, unsigned int nakLimit);
```

Reads data from the Android device into the array pointed to by *buff*. It reads *len* number of bytes. Reading is stopped when *len* bytes is read or *nakLimit* number of NAKs is received from the USB controller. In case of Full Speed USB a NAK will be generated every 1ms. (according to the second source link).

The return value is the number of bytes **available**, not the number of bytes read. If you read less bytes than there are available, those extra bytes seem to be ignored.

In my experiments I found out that NAK interval is much smaller. With my Arduino Mega ADK, I found out that one second wait equals roughly nakLimit of 14000.

Sources:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html (end of the page)
- [What is Nak Limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686130/what-is-nak-limit)